# Window screen capture on Adobe Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

Is there a way to take screenshot of the client's window using flex?

I found an example which uses java bridge, but i am looking for different solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to take a snapshot of the users screen?  OR just of the AIR App?

If you want to take a screencap of the user's screen, I'd look into [NitroScreenCap](http://simplifiedlogic.com/nitroscreencap). The 'generic' approach they use is that they wrote native code for each operating system and pack it up with the AIR app using a NativProcess.  I guess you could try to implement that yourself if needed.

If you just need a screencap of the Flex app; do some Googling.  You can get the BitMapData of any given Flex Component and turn that into an image.  Here are a few links that come up:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/11/16/taking-screenshots-in-flex-using-the-imagesnapshotcaptureimage-method/

http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/06/03/save-a-snapshot-image-of-a-flex-app-without-a-server/

http://www.mehtanirav.com/taking-a-snapshot-of-flex-app-from-flex/

Comment: Thanks! NitroScreencap is exactly what I need.

Comment: For capturing the app's screen, your first link works real well.  Combining with a call to `FileReference.save()` does a lot with little coding.